# Align to center a minted environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, minted

I would like to insert some code inside the `minted` environment when using `beamer`.

```
 \documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minted}[mathescape,
           gobble=2,
           linenos,
           fontsize=\tiny,
           framesep=2mm]{ocaml}
  let process il =
    let module IV = Instr_visitor in
    let visit i t = instrument i t in
    IV.map_instr IU.is_mem_write visit il
    |> insert_instr_list BEFORE !il_update
\end{minted}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, it just cannot be centralized even though I use the `centering` command. Could anyone shed some light on how to centralize it? Thank you!

Update: This is how it looks here:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put `minted` inside a `minipage` of sufficient width. Then put this inside a `center` environment.

(I am not sure why you are using `figure`. Do you need this to be a float?)

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{minted}[mathescape,
        gobble=2,
        linenos,
        fontsize=\tiny,
        framesep=2mm]{ocaml}
        let process il =
        let module IV = Instr_visitor in
        let visit i t = instrument i t in
        IV.map_instr IU.is_mem_write visit il
        |> insert_instr_list BEFORE !il_update
      \end{minted}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the width of the minipage needs to be specified manually for each snippet of code. Since the code is still left-aligned within the minipage env.

Comment: @SO_tourist Yes, you are right. But the if you use *sufficient* width, things are fine. So, there is no harm using a large common width for all.